# how to pop up a dialog when selecting an application from a list and save the entered data to database "mysqlite"?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to select an apps being displayed on a list and then getting a dialog to appear upon selecting any of them in which it prompts user to enter a passcode that is tied to that particular app and then saving the passcode to a database "mysqlite"

Below are my codes and what I would like to know is what do I need to change/add to the codes I have in order to achieve this?

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listapps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

java:

```
package com.example.androidproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class PasscodeLock extends Activity {
    private ListView lView;
    private ArrayList results;
    List<ResolveInfo> list;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_passcode_lock);

        results = new ArrayList();
        lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listapps);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) 
        {
            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
        lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_passcode_lock, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it appears to me that you have populated the list with *lView.setAdapter*, but you have not actually added the function that allows the User Selection to be selected.

And another thing is, it is usually preferred for the activity to be *ListActivity* instead of Activity, but of course that would depend on the implementation, because you might not have a fullscreen ListView.

Nonetheless, you can add an *OnItemClickListener* like this :

```
public class PasscodeLock extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener(){
   ....
}
```

which will trigger you to add another function called onItemClick, in which you will add the code to call the dialog which prompts the User to enter the passcode

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
   //call dialog
}
```

With regard to how to create that dialog I am not that sure as the dialogs I created are just to show messages to the user.

Comment: so how would I go about adding the function that allows the user to select the app without turning on or launching the app?